# Undocumented getopt in Smalltalk

Tags: command-line-arguments, smalltalk, getopt, gnu-smalltalk

I'm writing a command line app that encrypts passwords and decrypts password hashes. The docs for Getopt provide no examples, so I have no idea how to use the Getopt class. A few clues are scattered in [mailing list logs](http://forum.world.st/Re-Starting-with-smalltalk-td1290434.html).

In particular, I don't know the format of `with: pattern`, the string specifying CLI arguments and whether values are required, optional, or omitted.

ios7crypt.st:

```
"exec" "gst" "-f" "$0" "$0" "$@"
"exit"

| args password hash |

"Drop the program name."
"The shebang joins the arguments; we must split them."
args := (Smalltalk getArgv: 2) substrings: $ .

args do: [ :arg | Transcript show: 'Raw arg: ', arg; cr. ].

Getopt parse: args with: '-e: -d: -t' do: [ :opt :arg |
    Transcript show: 'Opt: ', (opt asString), ' Arg: ', arg; cr.

    "..."
].
```

Example run:

```
$ ./ios7crypt.st -e monkey
Raw arg: -e
Raw arg: monkey
Opt: e Arg: monkey
```

Previously, both `-e` and `monkey` were passed to the script, but Getopt's `do:` silently dropped `-e`, so the output looked like:

```
$ ./ios7crypt.st -e monkey
Raw arg: -e
Raw arg: monkey
Opt:  Arg: monkey
```

Comment: Ah, this is because :opt is a character, not a string, and therefore can't be appended with `,` (comma) to `Transcript show:`.

Comment: The docs are minimal but the source is heavily commented: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=smalltalk.git;a=blob;f=kernel/Getopt.st;h=dd6b7aaa7b579beba74f672a2ed8d939720ae194;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use #printString when debugging.  It will give a programmer-oriented representation (as opposed to #displayString).

BTW, you can use "$@" in the shebang invocation so that arguments are not joined.